# cant able to show the "To field" while sending the Mail from Android app

Tags: android, email, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have implemented the sen email functionality in my application.
For that i am using the below code:

```
Matcher matcher;
Pattern pattern;
String emailExpression ="^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]{2,4}$";
public static String email = "abc@xyz.com";

pattern = Pattern.compile(emailExpression);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        if(!matcher.matches())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Some Emails are not valid.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String mailto = (email);
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mailto);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Hello !!");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "MySendMail"));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Check Your Mail box for Delivery Report",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

All Works fine, But while i want to click on the Button of sending mail, i cant able to see that email address in to field which i have set as receipients.
What should i have to do ?
I want to show the email of receipients to the "To:" field while calling the SendEmail intent.
Help me for this.
thanks.

Comment: http://sspower3.blogspot.com/2011/09/sending-email.html check this

Comment: Ok. I have seen that, But there is nothing more change. And even in that example also i am not able to see the receipients email address that i have set in line "emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@pqr.com"});"

Comment: This code is working... are u checking ur code on emulator ???

Comment: yes I am checking it on emulator. But still cant able to see the recepients email address in "To:" field.

Comment: plz check it on device... email code will not work on emulator

Comment: You mean if i will check it on Device then it will show me the receipients static name that i have set as in "To:" field in My application ????